# How can I force read updates in all Smart Panel fields before reading it after a user updates and closes it?

Tags: acumatica

I have a smart panel where I preset a default value for a field within it. If the user changes the value of that field, when the popup is closed, the value remains the old, preset value. I've had this happen in two separate instances: one regarding setting a time and one regarding selectors. The fields are set to commit changes = true. Is there any way to force the code to grab the new value set by the user instead of keeping the value set before displaying the smart panel popup?

Example:

Smart panel has a view called Option. OptionA will be set to something before the popup is executed. After the popup is closed by the user, even if the user changed the selector's value, the code will see the originally set value to OptionA set programmatically before the popup was executed.

```
Option.Current.AOption = 10;
if (Option.AskExt(true) == WebDialogResult.OK)
{
    //This will display the original value
    Document.Ask(Option.Current.OptionA, MessageButtons.OK)
}
```

Initial popup:

[image]

User changed:

[image]

Popup after closing and executing Document.Ask():

[image]

Comment: Try to follow this pattern here and set the preset value in the parameter delegate too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51046982/7376238

Comment: From my experience it is usually an issue with the properties do or don't have set in the PXSmartPanel in the page. Can you include your page entry in your question, it might help. Also look at some other existing Acumatica smartpanels and compare or copy the same properties for one that work when a default is set and a value is changed. One example might be the sales order page copy order (panelCopyTo) panel.

Comment: HB, I tried adding the code that your link goes to, but it didn't work. Brendan, I've added a simplified version of my code. If you want the actual code, I'd rather send it privately because there is a lot of code. What I posted shows the core of the issue.

Comment: From my comment 'set the preset value in the parameter delegate', are you sure you did that? The code in your question doesn't do that, it sets the value outside and I think that's your problem. You shouldn't touch the Option dataview outside the delegate to initialize values, try this code and remove the Option.Current.AOption = 10 that is outside the parameter delegate:  Option.AskExt((graph, view) =>
{
  Option.Cache.ClearQueryCache();
  Option.View.Clear();
  Option.Clear();
  Option.Current.AOption = 10;
}) == WebDialogResult.OK)

Comment: HB, That worked perfectly! I understand what is going on there. I didn't realize there was an initialization handler on those. If you'd like, make it an answer and I'll give you the credit for answering it. Thanks again!